# Creating multiple tables from one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a single table in MYsql filled with all data (table: Archive)
I want to create multiple tables named with values in column "Names" containing alla data for every name

```
Ex. 
Table: Archive
column1     Names             column3   column4
1       John Smith          10/01/2014  35
2       John Smith          20/01/2014  36
1      Pinco Pallino        07/01/2014  30
1       Cippa Lippa         01/01/2014  20
2       Cippa Lippa         02/01/2014  21
3       Cippa Lippa         03/01/2014  19

Table: John Smith
column1 Names            column3    column4
1       John Smith          10/01/2014  35
2       John Smith          20/01/2014  36

Table: Pinco Pallino
column1 Names            column3    column4
1      Pinco Pallino        07/01/2014  30

Table: Cippa Lippa
column1 Names            column3    column4
1       Cippa Lippa         01/01/2014  20
2       Cippa Lippa         02/01/2014  21
3       Cippa Lippa         03/01/2014  19
```

For every kind of name in "Names" I have to build a table (related to the table:Archive) named with the value of "Names"
I need multiple tables to garant access to multiple users to only one table with a name

Can someone help me,please?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  It seems like a very bad idea.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: Is there any programming language you are willing to use? Or it's just SQL? And how about stored procedures?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than destroying your database structure, you could achieve the same access restriction using views:

```
CREATE VIEW cippa AS SELECT * FROM Archive WHERE Names = 'Cippa Lippa';
```

Answer (score 0):

If stored  procedures are acceptable, here's how it's done using a stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `split_archive`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE name VARCHAR(255);
    --A cursor to iterate distinct names
    DECLARE curNames CURSOR FOR SELECT Names FROM Archive GROUP BY Names;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    --Preparing a statement to create a table with parametric name and select condition
    PREPARE stmtCreateTable FROM 'CREATE TABLE `?` AS SELECT * FROM Archive WHERE Names = "?"';

    --Iterating and fetching each name
    OPEN curNames;
    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH curNames INTO name;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        --Since prepared statements only accept user variables
        SET @n = name;
        --Creating a table for the fetched name and populating it by executing the statement
        EXECUTE stmtCreateTable USING @n, @n;
    END LOOP;

    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmtCreateTable;
    CLOSE curNames;
END
$$
```